# Using C, get sum of every other digit not working at all

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to do a simple program that if I inputted - to keep things simple-

Enter

> 5235

Print out on screen

> length is 4
>   sum is 8

Enter

> 54468

Print

> length is 5
>   sum is 10

However, only the length seems to be working and I'm not sure why.

I got the total length of the number entered by the user and specified if number is odd then add the even count and vice versa, and yet it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
  long long cc_number;
  long long x;
  long long length;
  int sum, count = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("Please Enter Credit Card Number ");
    cc_number= get_long_long();
    x= cc_number;
  }
  while (x>0);

  while (x != 0)
  {
    x= x/10;
    length++;
  }

  x= cc_number;

  while (x != 0)
  {
    x= x/10;
    int digit= (int) (x % 10);
    count++;
    if ((count % 2 == 0) && (length %2 ==1))
    {
      sum=sum+digit;
    }
    else ((count % 2 == 1) && (length %2 ==0))
    {
      sum=sum+digit;
    }
  }

  printf("the sum is %i", sum);
  printf("the length of the digits is %lli", length);
}
```

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: 1) `sum` is uninitialized.

Comment: 2) `x= x/10;
    int digit= (int) (x % 10);` --> maybe `int digit = x % 10; x = x / 10;`

Comment: 3) `else ((count % 2 == 1) && (length %2 ==0))` --> `else if((count % 2 == 1) && (length %2 ==0))`

Comment: 4) `while (x>0);` --> `while (x<=0);`

Comment: 5) `length` is uninitialized. Other. Logic change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to initialise `sum` and `length` to `0`. Otherwise, they retain junk values
2. Your loop which accepts input is incorrect. You need

   ```
   do {

   ...} while (x <= 0);
   ```

   Otherwise you loop infinitely.
3. You need to interchange these 2 lines so they become:

   ```
   int digit = (int) (x % 10);
   x = x/10;
   ```

   Otherwise, in the i<sup>th</sup> iteration, digit will obtain the i+1<sup>th</sup> digit, not the i<sup>th</sup> digit.
4. `else (...)` is invalid syntax. You need `else if (...)`.

---

Full listing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  long long cc_number;
  long long x;
  long long length = 0;
  int sum = 0, count = 0;

  cc_number = (x = 54560);


  while (x != 0)
  {
    x= x/10;
    length++;
  }

  x= cc_number;

  while (x != 0)
  {
    x= x/10;
    int digit= (int) (x % 10);
    count++;
    if ((count % 2 == 0) && (length %2 ==1))
    {
      sum=sum+digit;
    }
    else if((count % 2 == 1) && (length %2 ==0))
    {
      sum=sum+digit;
    }
  }

  printf("The sum is %i\n", sum);
  printf("The length of the digits is %lli\n", length);
}
```

This prints out

```
$ ./a.out   
The sum is 10
The length of the digits is 5
```

(I've modified the print statements a bit.)

Comment: @Sundaze123 Added a slightly modified version of the code. Copy it and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    long long length = 0;
    int sum = 0, count = 0;
    long long cc_number;
    long long a = get_long("Please Enter Credit Card Number ");

    cc_number = a;

  while (a != 0)
  {
    a= a/10;
    length++;
  }

  a = cc_number;

  while (a != 0)
{
    int digit= a % 10;
    a= a/10;
    count++;

    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
      sum=sum+digit;
    }
}

  if (sum % 2 == 0)
  {
    printf("СС Number %lli\n", cc_number);
  }

  if ((count == 15) && (cc_number / 10000000000000 == 37 || cc_number / 10000000000000 == 34  ))
  {
    printf("American Express\n");
  }

  if ((count == 16) && (cc_number / 100000000000000 == 51))
  {
    printf("MarsterCard\n");
  }

  else
  {
    printf("INVALID\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).